# Caching query result using temporary table

Tags: amazon-redshift, ddl

I want to cache result of big select query for further use. The idea is to use temporary table (I believe that it persists for session or at least for transaction):

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE cache AS (SELECT * FROM t)
```

but when cache is already created I encounter following error:

```
Invalid operation: relation "cache" already exists;
```

There are no *IF NOT EXISTS* condition for *CREATE TEMP TABLE ... AS* statement. So question is, is there some workaround for this case?

Comment: What kind of workaround are you looking for? The table exists, you cannot create another table with the same name. Just don't create it multiple times within a session.

Comment: @zerkms I'm looking for alternatives of IF NOT EXISTS to avoid multiple creation

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeap, I use Amazon Redshift, which is based on Postgres 8.0.2

Comment: Then you shouldn't have tagged it with Postgres.

Comment: @Panlantic82 what is your expected result. What do you want to store in cache table - result for all "big queries" in session, result of last "big query" or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store just results for last "big query" in session then

```
Drop table if exists cache; 
Create temp table cache as 
select * from t where "your's conditions";
```

Dropping the cache table before will not block your creating table statement.

If you want to store results for all of your "big queries" then you will need some extra info in the naming of your cache.

You could check if temp table already exists in if statment

```
IF (select count(*) 
      from information_schema.tables 
     where table_name'cache' 
       and table_schema like 'pg_temp%')=0 THEN

  create temp table cache as 
  select * from t where "your's conditions";
ELSE
  select * from cache where "your's conditions";
END;
```

Comment: Cześć Grzegorz. Your answer has been flagged as low quality. So, consider adding some text explaining your answer to avoid deletion.

Comment: why should i drop table every time. I need cache that persist for a session

Comment: What is your purpose to store result for just one query , and this is not possible to change during session  or do you want to store results for all of your "big queries" in that session or do you want to store results just for last big query?
I assumed that you want to store results for last big query then why there is a drop.

Comment: @GrzegorzGrabek I want to use stored results for several big queries in session

Comment: @Panlantic82 ok. Pls describe (best in your question) how do you see that functionality? Because we don't know if queries results are always the same structure or different structure. How do you want to call them back (what will be unique ID of results)? And most important why do you want to store cache results on DB side, not on the client side?

Comment: @GrzegorzGrabek I have a lot of queries that using different subsets of the same large select. I initially thought that subsetting from cache (which we retrieve once) is kinda good in terms of performance

Comment: @Panlantic82 - if this is same large select then materialized view should be a perfect solution for your problem. Just remember to refresh it on a daily (or often) routine
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html

Comment: @GrzegorzGrabek there are no materialized views in amazon redshift. the workaround is to use CREATE TABLE statements, but in my case I have permissions only for creating temp tables.

Comment: @Panlantic82 Seems that we return to what I wrote first then. Create a temp table for a session with all data from your SQL, create indexes for fast filtering results. A then you will have to create SQL that use your temp table instead of standard SQL you use now.

Comment: @GrzegorzGrabek If query executed for 2nd+ time I encounter following error: 'Invalid operation: relation "cache" already exists'. The problem and question is that there are no "IF NOT EXISTS" for "CREATE TEMP TABLE" in redshft. It's possible to create cache once manually, but I need lazy automated solution.

Comment: @Panlantic82 I edited the answer. Hope it will be useful for you now. If not give a sign.

Comment: @GrzegorzGrabek damn, Amazon Redshift is so frustrating. It doesn't even have if-then-else procedural statements.